# Add dynamic buttons to the beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add couple of buttons in to a DIV.

```
var newVr = "";
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
  newVr += '<button type="button" class="abc">New</button>';
}
document.getElementById('extraDIV')innerHTML += newVr;
```

Instead of adding the buttons to the end of the buttons, how do I add the new buttons at the beginning?

Expected output after new buttons are added e.g.

[new] [new] [old] [old] [old] [old] [old] [old]

Comment: `document.getElementById('extraDIV').innerHTML = newVr + document.getElementById('extraDIV').innerHTML;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**prepend()**](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
  $('#extreDIV').prepend('<button type="button" class="abc">New</button>');
}
```

```js
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  $('#extreDIV').prepend('<button type="button" class="abc">New</button>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extreDIV">
  <button type="button" class="abc">Old</button>
  <button type="button" class="abc">Old</button>
  <button type="button" class="abc">Old</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tagged the question with jquery

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    $("#extraDIV").prepend('<button type="button" class="abc">New</button>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend) like,

```
var newVr = "";
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
     newVr += '<button type="button" class="abc">New</button>';
}
$('#extreDIV').prepend(newVr);
```

```js
var newVr = "";
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
     newVr += '<button type="button" class="abc">New '+(i+1)+'</button>';
}
$('#extreDIV').prepend(newVr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="extreDIV"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`Node.insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

```js
// Create a new, plain <span> element
var sp1 = document.createElement("span");
sp1.innerHTML = 'I am new span ';

// Get a reference to the element, before we want to insert the element
var sp2 = document.getElementById("childElement");

// Get a reference to the parent element
var parentDiv = sp2.parentNode;

// Insert the new element into the DOM before sp2
parentDiv.insertBefore(sp1, sp2);
```

```html
<div id="parentElement">
  <span id="childElement">foo bar</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the example in jsFiddld `https://jsfiddle.net/92j135v9/1/prepend`.

Also check the jQuery documentation for prepand `http://api.jquery.com/prepend/` for more examples.